# Import .bacpac file in SQL Server on AWS RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

I'm trying to import a `.bacpac` file into SQL Server on AWS RDS. I'm using SQL Server Management Studio.

While importing I'm getting an error:

> Can not create db because it does not exist or user does not have permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting the same error as well.

Here's what I did:

You need to install ***sqlpackage.exe*** to continue with the next step. Here's the link to [download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-download?view=sql-server-ver15)

sqlpackage.exe is usually located at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DAC\bin`

Now run the following command:

```
sqlpackage /a:Import /sf:"<absolute-path-to-bacpac-file>" /tsn:"<database.rds.amazonaws.com>" /tdn:<dbname> /tu:<username> /tp:<password>
```

Comment: I have tried everything but nothing worked. But the above solution worked like charm. Thanks for the post.